# Convert newData to int/long in firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am setting security rules so user can increment a value only if `(newData + alreadyInsertedData) < limit`

but firebase security rules editor showing below error

> Invalid + expression: right operand is not a number or string.

Can we convert newData to int/long so we can add it and check if condition?

the rule I have error in,

```js
".write":"auth != null && ((root.child(\"GameResult\").child($adminRef).child($gameName).child($jodi).child($uid).val()+newData) < root.child(\"Limits\").child($adminRef).child(\"maxAmountOnEachJodi\").val())"
```

complete rules(please ignore other issues right now),

```js
{
   "rules":{
      ".read":"auth != null",
     // ".write":"auth != null",
      "GameResult":{
         "$adminRef":{
            "$gameName":{
               "$jodi":{
                  "$uid":{
                     ".write":"auth != null && ((root.child(\"GameResult\").child($adminRef).child($gameName).child($jodi).child($uid).val()+newData) < root.child(\"Limits\").child($adminRef).child(\"maxAmountOnEachJodi\").val())"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

database nodes are below:
the value(red marked) in GameResult node should not cross the value(blue marked) in Limit node.

GameResult node:

[image: gameresult node]

Limit node:

[image]

Finally what I want is:

`(GameResult/*/*/*/*:value+ newData) <= (Limits/*/*/maxAmountOnEachJodi:value)`

Answer (score 0):

I found it, newData is kind of a object which has a val() function. So calling `newData.val()` will get the job done.